# Custom property name for bootstrap-nav-tree

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using this directive https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree for my tree and I'm fetching data remotely from server. I'm not sure if this is a requirement from the directive, but i cant display my data unless there is a "label" property defined in my database when fetching.

```
// this works okay since there is a property 'label'
$scope.tree = [
    {
      label:  "Stack",
      children: ['child1', 'child2']
    }
];


// this doesnt because of the 'name' property.
$scope.tree = [
    {
      name: "Stack",
      children: ['child1', 'child2']
    }
]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of the directive *There is a long-form for elements, in which each node is an object with a **"label"**, and optionally other stuff like "data", and "children".*

The directive expects the key `label` to be present at all times.